# (Android) Getting a GPS Location via Service / App Stopped Working

Tags: java, android, gps, location, bindservice

I'm writing an app in which the main activity should bind to a service when clicking on a button. The service should get the GPS location. I keep getting the message "Unfortunately, the app has stopped" whenever debugging...

Here's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.MyApp"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
                android:name=".Main"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
                android:name=".GPSLocation" android:label="GPS Location"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE"
                android:enabled="true">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here's Main.java:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    // UI elements
    private static Context context;
    private TextView lblLocation;
    private Button btnStartService;
    private Button btnShowLocation;
    private Button btnGetClosestBusStop;

    GPSLocation mService;
    Location location;
    boolean mBound = false;

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
        btnStartService = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartService);
        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnGetClosestBusStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetClosestBusStop);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, GPSLocation.class);
        btnStartService.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // First we need to check availability of play services
                if (checkPlayServices()) {
                    //getApplicationContext().bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                    bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                }
            }
        });

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mBound) {
                    displayLocation();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /**
     * Method to verify google play services on the device
     * */
    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Method to display the location on UI
     * */
    private void displayLocation() {
        location = mService.mLastLocation;
        if (location != null) {
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
        } else {
            lblLocation.setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder binder) {
            GPSLocation.MyBinder bin = (GPSLocation.MyBinder) binder;
            mService = bin.getService();
            location = bin.getLocation();
            mBound = true;
            Log.d("ServiceConnection", "connected");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
            Log.d("ServiceConnection","disconnected");
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Here's GPSLocation.java:

```
public class GPSLocation extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = GPSLocation.class.getSimpleName();
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyBinder();
    private Messenger outMessenger;
    public Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters

    public class MyBinder extends Binder {
        GPSLocation getService() {
            return GPSLocation.this;
        }
        Location getLocation() {
            return GPSLocation.this.mLastLocation;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Building the Google API client
        buildGoogleApiClient();

        createLocationRequest();

        togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Creating Google API client object
     * */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }

    /**
     * Method to toggle periodic location updates
     * */
    public void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     * */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google API callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;
    }
}
```

And here's the logcat message:

```
11-17 03:44:58.157  29408-29408/com.WaitOrWalk E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.MyApp, PID: 29408
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.MyApp.GPSLocation: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2912)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1455)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlh.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzli.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.MyApp.GPSLocation.startLocationUpdates(GPSLocation.java:107)
            at com.MyApp.GPSLocation.togglePeriodicLocationUpdates(GPSLocation.java:87)
            at com.MyApp.GPSLocation.onCreate(GPSLocation.java:55)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2894)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1455)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I'd really appreciate some help, been stuck on this for a while... The app crashes on `bindService(intent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Comment: So what's the logcat message?

Comment: Now that I looked at the logcat message again, it's different than before when I was getting errors, much shorter...

Comment: @Bartek you have to connect googleApiClient